# Firebase Dynamic links behaviour on iOS 8 vs. iOS 10

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have an app already on App Store that has a custom URL scheme registered.
I implemented Firebase Dynamic Links for the new version of the app.
When testing the new links, when I open a FDL with the old App installed on iOS 10, I get redirected to the App Store to update the app.
When I open a FDL with the old App installed on iOS 8, the old app is opened because openUrl for my URL scheme is triggered. My app crashes because of this, because the old app is unable to handle such link.
I expected that on iOS 8 it would also redirect me to the App Store to update the App as it does on iOS 10.

Even sending imv=min_app_version (as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually)) as a part of the FDL does not help.

Why is this behavior different between iOS 8 and 10? Is there any way how to stop this happening on iOS 8?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS 8 does support custom URL schemes pretty well, also iOS 8 does not supports Universal Links. Because of these reasons Firebase Dynamic Links will use custom URL scheme to detect that your App is installed/not-installed on iOS 8 (and open the App).

iOS 9 and above do not have nice support for custom URL schemes and these OS's have Universal Links. Firebase Dynamic Links will use Universal links there.

About `imv`: we do provide imv parameter, but contrary to Android, we do not know version of the installed iOS App. We expect App to handle `imv`. For example if App that opened the link have lover version number than specified in `imv`, App should show message to the user and redirect to AppStore for upgrade.

One way how you can resolve this situation is to create new custom URL scheme that does not exists in your already released App versions. In this way older Apps, that crashing, will not be opened by Firebase Dynamic Links.

Comment: "iOS 9 and above do not have nice support for custom URL schemes", I don't think this is right?

Comment: Before iOS9 it was possible to detect if App is installed (or not installed) and open the App with custom URL scheme. From iOS9 custom URL scheme still works, but if you invoke a custom scheme, and App happens to be not installed, user will stuck on nasty error screen. Also there is a popup when trying to invoke a custom URL scheme. This what I mean by "do not have nice support".